# Using xarp on a network

Tags: network, network-scanners

I am slightly worried about getting into trouble...

I have installed Xarp and when I opened it, it started listing IPs. I am on a public network, so would it get flagged on the administrator's side??

Comment: you are worried about getting into trouble because you have monitored traffic on that public network ?

Comment: I assume you mean xarp?

Comment: Without inspecting the program myself, I suspect that it just listens to the network. There would be nothing to detect.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the network is concerned, no, you do not need to be concerned.  XArp listens to ARP *broadcast packets* which are sent to your machine, it does not generate traffic (emphasis mine):

> [XArp](http://www.xarp.net/) will inspect every ARP packet and report attacks against remote
>   machines. Some inspection modules can only work for the local machine
>   (e.g. StaticPreserve), but most modules will not need any local
>   information. *They monitor each ARP packet* and can thus detect ARP
>   attacks against other machines. Be sure to deploy XArp on a machine
>   that sees all network traffic from the whole subnet. *XArp can only
>   monitor and inspect packets that it can see.*

Depending on your environment, it is possible that your Administrator does see programs; for example, many anti-virus packages will alert upon security tools.  However, I would think XArp is unlikely to trigger alerts, it's a purely defensive tool with no offensive capabilities.